# How to apply CSS to this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm working on an app which requires showing images according to the user's device. So I'm using the following Javascript code to show the menus and their icons:

```
  var $imgsrc;

  if(dummy_url_decode(results.rows.item(i).title) == "Web Info")

     $imgsrc = "icons/web_info.png";

  if(dummy_url_decode(results.rows.item(i).title) == "Misc.")

     $imgsrc = "icons/misc.png";
```

Now I want to apply condition if the device is with retina display then it should show different icons for it. I have the media query syntax but dont know how to change the img path from CSS. Can anybody help me? The media query I'm using is:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change attributes from CSS.

Your best option would probably be to use a `<span>` or `<div>` instead of an image, style it to `display:inline-block` with suitable `width` and `height`, and then you can change the `background-image` property in your media queries.

Something like this:

> HTML:
>
> ```
> <span id="myIcon"></span>
> ```
>
> CSS:
>
> ```
> #myIcon {
>     display:inline-block;
>     width:32px;
>     height:32px;
>     background-image:url('icons/some_icon.png');
> }
> @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) {
>     #myIcon {
>         width:64px;
>         height:64px;
>         background-image:url('icons/some_hi-res_icon.png');
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I appreciate you reply, but can you explian it with sample code? I'm new to CSS and javascript so it will be helpful to me!